# How can we differentiate between a signal cable and electric cable in automotive wiring harness?

Tags: automotive

If I have a bunch of wires of an automotive harness, but I cannot differentiate between electrical wires that transmit the 12V and others that transmit control module signals.

Comment: You should be able to find a wiring diagram with pinout and color codes online.

Comment: Get the wiring diagram and you definitely need to know which car manufacturer as they don't all use the same color codes - makes life fun :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an oscilloscope nowadays for $45. It's not a very good scope, but more than adequate to distinguish 12 VDC from serial communications (CAN or LIN bus). Some "signals" may just be on-off DC rather than a data stream. In that case, you may have to monitor during a drive or when operating various controls.

A couple of "insulation piercing" probes would be helpful as well.

Comment: Check out a "logic analyzer" if you want to decode the protocol at all.  (I think a scope is totally sufficient as too for this!)

Comment: @Leroy105 would you mean a "tool"?